# How to make 2 way access verification in django?

Tags: python, django, whatsapp

I would like to improve security for access, making a 2 way access verification using a code to send to whatsapp or by using a qrcode.
Is there any program or library with such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know [Django Two-Factor Authentication](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), it allow users to authenticate through call, text messages (SMS) or by using a token generator app like Google Authenticator.

I don't know any library that allow whatsapp code, but you can use Django-two-factor-authenticate to generate the code, and use another library to send this code to WhatsApp.